# R when debugging, is there a way to skip a specific statement?

Tags: r, debugging

I think most people has met the same problem with me

```
f1 = function(){
function1() #takes 1hour
b = function2() #takes 2hours
c = function3(b)
statement1
statement2
...}
```

suppose function1 and function2 is very time consuming, I want to skip at least one of them to see if the rest part of my function works

question1:
Is there a way to skip function1?

question2:
Is there a way to skip function2? this function2 produce result b which is critical for the function to continue, In java there is a way to hack value for b and make the process continue, is that also possible in R?

Comment: You can always comment `function1()` if the calculations of `function1` are independent of rest of the functions. For `function2()` can you set some hard coded value for `b` ?

Comment: First thanks for answering! comment out is ok when your structure is simple but when the structure get complex then sometimes I don't remember which one I need to dis-comment, the following answer that redefine function on spot is more convinient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** When in the debugger you can redefine the functions on the spot.  For example, any time before getting to the point where `function1` is invoked enter this into the debugger:

```
function1 <- list
```

Now invoking `function1()` actually invokes `list()` .

This could alternately be done outside of `f1` before invoking it.  In that case we may wish to store `function1` in another name first to make it easy to revert back to it.

```
function1.orig <- function1
function1 <- list
```

Later, after we have completed our debugging, we can revert `function1` back by writing:

```
function1 <- function1.orig
```

**2)** For `function2` you may wish to redefine it as follows where 32 is the critical value needed later.

```
function2 <- function() 32
```

Comment: Thanks! redefine the function on the debugging spot is practical, although I am sure there are some other ways to solve this,  but your method is indeed helpful